# How to remove .php extension from web.config file from wordpress root folder?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, content-management-system

I have static PHP pages in the WordPress root folder. On the `web.config` file, I changed the default file to static PHP file `home.php`. I am having a few static PHP pages and a few WordPress pages for my website. For WordPress pages, I changed SEO friendly URL using permalinks, but static PHP pages not able to remove `.php` extensions.

Like this:

`http://reactore.com/contact-us/` --- WordPress page
`http://reactore.com/about-us.php`  --- static PHP page

This is my `web.config` file:

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="WPurls" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

*[Click to view my web.config file at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/hzqzpqua/)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code in your web config:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: if i add this web.config file static php pages are working fine but wordpress pages giving error.

Comment: you have to tell your web server you are using index.php page of your default page.

Comment: Iam not using index.php as default page [click here to view my web.config](https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/hzqzpqua/)

Comment: For wordpress you can set this rule:

    <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url=".*" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>